# Should we delete spam links as well as flagging the post?

Tags: discussion, support, spam

I recently reviewed this question [how can I increase my website loading speed](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/96097/how-can-i-increase-my-website-loading-speed).
It was a single line question including a link to a site.

> I think my website speed is not good. so how can I increase its speed? [enter link description here]

During my review [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/76744) I flagged the question as spam and just deleted the link.

The [flag](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/117311?group=2&status=2) was accepted but the review rejected:

> Rejected 1 hour ago:
>   ChrisF♦ reviewed this 1 hour ago: Reject
>   This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

The thinking behind my edit was that taken the fact I considered the post as spam I should at least delete the link as well, since it would be visible on the site for the whole time and until the post is deleted or edited anyway by the author. Was my thinking wrong?

*Should we **not** delete spam links as well as flagging a post?*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is covered in [Should Spam posts be edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110030/should-spam-posts-be-edited)

No, spam posts (if they are really spam) should not be edited in any way, so that other users see them for what they are, and flag accordingly.

Comment: Having the spam present when the postis deleted feeds the anti spam system too. Deleting the spam will give the system false information.